# Application opening the login page again after logging in

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver

Hi i am working on Selenium C# and has implemented some methods using pagefactory.

My issue is Application opens a new instance of login page after logging in.

How we can maintain only a single login.

My Pages are as follows

Base Page-
**This page will instantiate the driver**

```
namespace POM_Selenium_VSS.Pages
{
class BasePage
{
    public IWebDriver driver = null;
    public BasePage(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.InitElements(driver, this);
    }

}
}
```

Home Page-**This will do the actual login**

```
namespace POM_Selenium_VSS.Pages
{
class HomePage : BasePage
{

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "UserNameInputText")]
    public IWebElement UserName { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "Brand")]
    public IWebElement BrandName { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "CmdLogin")]
    public IWebElement Btn_Login { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "Cancel")]
    public IWebElement Btn_Cancel { get; set; }

    public HomePage(IWebDriver driver):base(driver)
    {
      driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://153.112.61.197/vss_connect_testr1/Login/Login.aspx?nextview=Welcome");

    }


public void login(string username,string brand)
    {
        UserName.SendKeys(username);
        SelectElement Brand = new SelectElement(BrandName);
        Brand.SelectByValue(brand);
        Btn_Login.Click();
        if(driver.FindElements(By.Id("Cancel")).Count!=0)
            {
            Btn_Cancel.Click();
            }          
   }

}
}
```

Create Quotation Page-**This page will launch the create quotation page after successful logging in**

```
namespace POM_Selenium_VSS.Pages
{
class Create_Quotation:HomePage
{
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "PageHeader_CloseApplication")]
    public IWebElement close_vss { get; set; }



    public Create_Quotation(IWebDriver driver) : base(driver)
    {

    }
    public void launch_create_quotation()
    {
        close_vss.Click();
    }
}
}
```

Login C# file-**This is a C# unit test file  which will do the actual operations.**

```
namespace POM_Selenium_VSS.Tests
{
[TestClass]
public class Login
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Initalise_login()
    {
        IWebDriver driver = null;
        try
        {
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            HomePage homepage = new HomePage(driver);
            homepage.login("TYP40FI", "Volvo");
            Create_Quotation quotation = new Create_Quotation(driver);
            quotation.launch_create_quotation();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("User does not exists");
            Console.Write(e.StackTrace);
        }


    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're establishing 2 driver threads. One in your Base Page that gets told what to do by the Home Page and another that is being told what to do by your Test. You should have [Setup] & [TearDown] attributes that initialize your driver before/after each test run. I've provided examples from one of my Sample Projects for your comparison.

**DriverUtil (To initialize driver)**

```html
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using System;

namespace SampleProj.Utilities
{
    class DriverUtil
    {
        public static RemoteWebDriver driver {get; set;}
    }
}
```

**Login Page**

```html
using SampleProj.Utilities;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects;
using System;

namespace SampleProj.Pages
{
    class Login : DriverUtil
    {
        public Login() 
        { 
          PageFactory.InitElements(DriverUtil.driver, this); 
        }

        // Email
        [FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "email")]
        public IWebElement Email { get; set; }

        // Password
        [FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "password")]
        public IWebElement Password { get; set; }

        // Login Button
        [FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "submitter")]
        public IWebElement LoginButton { get; set; }


        // Enter and Submit Login Credentials
        public Dashboard SubmitLogin(string email, string password)
        {
            Email.SendKeys(email);
            Password.SendKeys(password);
            LoginButton.Click();
            // BaseUtil.cs contains shared functionality
            BaseUtil.WaitForPage();
            Console.WriteLine("Login Credentials Submitted");
            return new Dashboard();
        }
      }
  }
```

**Tests**

```html
using SampleProj.Pages;
using SampleProj.Utilities;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;

namespace SampleProj.Tests
{
    class LoginTests : DriverUtil
    {
        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            string URL = "your website url";
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(URL);
            Console.WriteLine("Opened Browser & Navigated to URL");
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void TearDown()
        {
            driver.Close();
            driver.Quit();
            Console.WriteLine("Browser Closed.");
        }

        [Test]  /// Successful Login
        public void Successful_Login()
        {
            Login pgLogin = new Login();
            Home pgHome = pgLogin.SubmitValidCredentials("user email", "user password");
            pgHome.ConfirmHomePage();

            Console.WriteLine("Test Complete");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect.
Thanks for the quick solution Loffin.
How can i close this thread and upvote

Comment: Just below the up and down arrows on my answer is a faded checkmark. If you select it, it will designate my answer as accepted for your question and essentially marks this one as done. Very glad it helped.